# How can I move across two child view controllers with autolayout?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm making a view controller with a left sidebar container view and a main container view that is a navigation controller.

Here's a picture of it:
[image]

I'm using autolayout so I may only use constraints.

How can I make the screen show only part of this view controller?
I can't change the frame because I'm using autolayout...

Comment: Which part do you want it to show?

Comment: The right container view. However it ends up showing me this... http://imgur.com/qpVPShX

Comment: So you want the width of the left container to become 0, effectively? Or maybe for the X origin to move to the left such that the right container is the only thing visible?

Comment: For the x origin to move to the left so that way the right container is the only thing visible. I am using autolayout, which is where I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

First, try just adjusting the frame of your containing view (the one holding those two containers) to move it left.

In theory it's just `[rightContainerView superview]`

If that isn't working for you, you can always iterate through the constraints that are set on either view and remove/adjust them until you get the layout you want. You can hold on to the constraints you remove in an array on your view controller, then add them back when you want it to be restored.

See `[view constraints]`

Comment: But isn't it the rule of autolayout that you don't touch the frame?

Comment: Not necessarily. The purpose of auto-layout is to allow you to not have to touch the frame of the views when you want their layouts to be automatically laid out. When you need to explicitly move a view, you still have to explicitly move the view. If you want to *change* the constraints, you can of course do that at any time. But it sounds like you just want to move a view over, then back, leaving the relationships between the other parts intact.

Comment: If you have some time, the videos from WWDC 2012 and 2013 that cover autolayout are *extremely* helpful in clarifying many of the most common use-cases of autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

You just adjust the constant parameter of a constraint. So you would want your two container views to have constraints to the top and bottom of the superview. The right container should be pinned to the right side of the superview, and have a 0 length constraint from its left side to the right side of the left container view (but no fixed width). Give the left container view a constraint to the left edge of the superview and a width constraint. That should give you sufficient constraints to define your starting point. Make an IBOutlet to the left container view's constraint to the left edge of the superview (lets call it leftCon). Then when you want to move that left container view off screen to the left, change its leftCon constraint's constant value:

```
self.leftCon.constant = -200; // this will move it 200 point to the left, and the right view will expand by 200 points.
```

Comment: This makes my titleView look scrunched up as in this pic... http://i.imgur.com/DxDbux0.png The only thing that I have there is a titleView that has an image (aspectFit) and a search navigationItem on the top right of the navigation bar.

Comment: @AnthonyGlyadchenko, I'm not sure what I'm looking for in your image. What do you want to happen when the left view moves out of the way? Do you want the right view to expand, or is some of its content hidden when both views are on screen, and when the right view moves over to fill the screen that hidden content is revealed?