# How can I make my UINavigationBar not look all scrunched up?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, autolayout

Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282806/75350) of making a view controller with two child controllers that pans similar to a sidebar layout, makes my navigation bar look all scrunched up when the sidebar is opened.

[image]

Is there a way for me to fix this autolayout issue?

EDIT -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  self.leftCon.constant = -280;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  //[self slideToTheRight];
}

-(void)slideToTheRight{
  self.sidebarOpened = YES;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.leftCon.constant = 0;



  }];
}

-(void) slideBack{
  self.sidebarOpened = NO;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.leftCon.constant = -280;
  }];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Basically the right bar button item and titleView somehow end up squished against the right side of the screen when the left constraint is changed from -280 to 0.

Comment: Without seeing your current layout, it's going to be difficult…

Comment: I just followed the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282806/75350

Comment: And the constraints on the items that are "scrunched up"?

Comment: No... I mean that everything on the navigation bar just pools up on the right side of the screen whenever the navigation bar is even slightly visible.

Comment: Are you designing this in iOS 7?

Comment: Yes I am, but this is using autolayout which works in iOS 6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to remove the constraint for the right child view trailing width.